# code goes into infinite loop when updating table's column

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

expert.
I'm new to PLSQL programming.
More than 200 tables have 'EXAMPLE' columns.
I want to update the column 'EXAMPLE' with 'YES'.
The purpose of the following code is to update the 'EXAMPLE' column for every 10000 records.
But I think the following code enters an infinite loop.
Where am I making a mistake?.
how can i fix this?

```
declare
v_match_count integer;
table_name varchar2(30);
begin
  v_match_count:=0;
 for tablolar in  
 (
  SELECT table_name 
FROM   user_tab_columns,user_objects 
WHERE 
user_tab_columns.table_name=user_objects.object_name and user_objects.object_type not in ('VIEW')  AND
 column_name IN ( 'FILE_NO', 'PROT_NO' ) 
GROUP  BY table_name 
HAVING Count(*) > 1
  ) loop   
    begin       
       -- v_match_count:=v_match_count+1;
        --              dbms_output.put_line(tablolar.table_name||' = '||v_match_count);
                              WHILE TRUE LOOP                           
                                   IF tablolar.table_name||'.EXAMPLE' IS NOT    NULL THEN --the line I changed in the code.
                                       --dbms_output.put_line(tablolar.table_name||' = '||v_match_count||' girdi.');
                                       execute immediate 'UPDATE HASTANE.'||tablolar.table_name|| ' SET EXAMPLE=''YES'' WHERE '||tablolar.table_name||'.EXAMPLE IS NULL AND ROWNUM<10000'  ;
                                       COMMIT;                                                                    
                                   END IF;
                                   IF tablolar.table_name||'.EXAMPLE' IS    NULL THEN --the line I changed in the code.
                                   EXIT;
                                   end if;
                          --  v_match_count:=v_match_count+1;
                            END LOOP;
             v_match_count:=v_match_count+1;           
                    dbms_output.put_line(tablolar.table_name||' = '||v_match_count);            
      end;
     end loop;             
end;
```

Comment: I didn't analyze the details of your code, but the `IF tablolar.table_name||'.EXAMPLE' IS NOT NULL`  condition never appears to exit your `WHILE` loop. If that condition is true, does the code cause it to become false?

Answer (score 0):

In the test for 'EXAMPLE' the value will never be NULL so you will never exit the loop.  Try checking for the existence of the column 'EXAMPLE' in your query, then you can just do the update for each table and the loop will exit when all the records are read.

```
declare
v_match_count integer;
v_record_count INTEGER;
table_name varchar2(30);

begin
  v_match_count:=0;
  v_record_count := 0;
 for tablolar in  
 (
  SELECT table_name 
FROM   user_tab_columns,user_objects 
WHERE 
user_tab_columns.table_name=user_objects.object_name and user_objects.object_type not in ('VIEW')  AND
 column_name IN ( 'FILE_NO', 'PROT_NO' ) 
 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_tab_columns x
        WHERE x.table_name = user_tab_columns.table_name AND x.column_name = 'EXAMPLE')
GROUP  BY table_name 
HAVING Count(*) > 1
  ) loop   
      BEGIN  
            --- Get the record cound
            execute immediate 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' || 'HASTANE.' ||tablolar.table_name || ' WHERE '||tablolar.table_name||'.EXAMPLE IS NULL'
                        INTO v_record_count;

             --- Do we have anything to update?
             IF NVL(v_record_count,0) > 0 THEN

                 --- Update all the records that are NULL
                 FOR v_match_count IN 1..v_record_count LOOP

                      execute immediate 'UPDATE HASTANE.'||tablolar.table_name|| ' SET EXAMPLE=''YES'' WHERE '||tablolar.table_name||'.EXAMPLE IS NULL'  ;

                      --- Check if it's time to COMMIT (every 10000 records)
                      IF MOD(v_match_count, 10000) = 0 THEN
                       COMMIT;
                      END IF;

                 END LOOP;

                 --- COMMIT remaining records since last COMMIT
                 COMMIT;                                                                    
             END IF;
      end;
     end loop;             
end;
```

Comment: thanks.
Your code is working.but it only updates 10000 of my 1 million records.
eg 10001. or 20000 or 50000 record has not been updated.I want to update all 1 million records.I want to update every 10000 records and continue to the end of the tables.

Comment: The UPDATE command you had is controlling the records updated.  You are updating 'ROWNUM < 10000'.  I suggest using a parameter instead of hardcoding the 10000.  Do you know how to do that?

Comment: thanks.
code is running.
but I don't want to be at the computer all the time for codes.
I want the cod to run automatically each time.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to update the "example" columns of every 10000 rows at the same time.
for example, I have 4 tables with an 'example' column in my database.
the name of these tables is table1, table2, table3, table4
for example
Suppose there are 30000 records in Table 1.
update table1 'example' column to first 10000

Comment: then run the 'commit' command.
then
table1 'example' column update records between 10000-20000
then run the 'commit' command.
then

Comment: table1 update 'example' column 20000-30000
then run the 'commit' command.
then
Since the number of records in Table1 is over, update proceeds to table2.
I wanted the same operations to be done for table2, table3, and table4.

Comment: I've revised the code to show how to commit every 10000 records.

Comment: Made a correction... I had forgotten to take out your check for 10000 on your update.